# How can I hide the zoom control in an Android webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

As per the title, how I can hide the zoom control in a webview?

Answer (score 24):

You should use WebSettings and set [setDisplayZoomControls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDisplayZoomControls%28boolean%29) to false. This will allow the user to still use the pinch to zoom but the controls will not be displayed.

```
    myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: ...The method setDisplayZoomControls(boolean) is undefined for the type WebSettings

Comment: this command work only on SDK 11 or greater....there is a workaround to have the same effect with previeus sdk?

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls (false);
```

Is what you're looking for I think.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29

Comment: Play with WebSettings.setSupportZoom(true); see if some combination of this and setBuiltInZoomControls() will allow you pinch zoom but will still hide the buttons. Unfortuneately though I am not certain that it is possible before API 11 to allow pinch zoom, but hide the buttons. Unless you implement the pinch zoom logic yourself.

Answer (score 0):

well, infact ,

```
WebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls (false); (<11)
```

and

```
myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

shared same code

```
 /**
 * Sets whether the zoom mechanism built into WebView is used.
 */
public void setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean enabled) {
    mBuiltInZoomControls = enabled;
    mWebView.updateMultiTouchSupport(mContext);
}



 /**
 * Sets whether the on screen zoom buttons are used.
 * A combination of built in zoom controls enabled
 * and on screen zoom controls disabled allows for pinch to zoom
 * to work without the on screen controls
 */
public void setDisplayZoomControls(boolean enabled) {
    mDisplayZoomControls = enabled;
    mWebView.updateMultiTouchSupport(mContext);
}
```

just have different names

Comment: Maybe on older versions (to keep compatibility), because setDisplayZoomControls really hides the controls and setBuiltInZoomControls helps to enable the zoom feature.